# Why doesn't `shutdown now` (with no other arguments) run init scripts?

Tags: shutdown, raspbian, init

I'm running Rasbpian on my Pi, and I have a script in `/etc/rc0.d` (or more precisely, a symlink to `/etc/init.d/myscript.sh`) that does some GPIO output to notify the user that power can be shut off.

If I run `sudo shutdown -h now`, the script runs, and the system goes down.
If I run `sudo shutdown now`, the script does *not* run, but the system goes down.

I cannot find any documentation that states what should really happen when running `shutdown now` with no other arguments.

What difference does the `-h` make in this case? Does running `shutdown now` really not invoke runlevel `0`?

Update: I found [this doc (unixhelp.ed.ac.uk)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?shutdown+8), saying that the default behaviour with no arguments is to go to runlevel `1`. But I have a script in `/etc/rc1.d`, too, that does not run on `shutdown`.

As requested, here are the first few lines from `last -x` (the arrows are mine):

```
pi       pts/3        vidar-ramdals-ma Fri Jan  9 18:07   still logged in   
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.12.28+         Fri Jan  9 18:04 - 18:07  (00:02)    
reboot   system boot  3.12.28+         Fri Jan  9 18:04 - 18:07  (00:02)    
shutdown system down  3.12.28+         Fri Jan  9 18:04 - 18:04  (00:00)    
runlevel (to lvl 0)   3.12.28+         Fri Jan  9 18:04 - 18:04  (00:00) <- shutdown -h now   
pi       pts/3        vidar-ramdals-ma Fri Jan  9 18:02 - down   (00:01)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.12.28+         Fri Jan  9 18:01 - 18:04  (00:02)    
reboot   system boot  3.12.28+         Fri Jan  9 18:01 - 18:04  (00:02)    
pi       pts/3        vidar-ramdals-ma Fri Jan  9 17:57 - crash  (00:04) <- shutdown now   
pi       pts/3        vidar-ramdals-ma Fri Jan  9 01:30 - 01:34  (00:03)    
pi       pts/3        vidar-ramdals-ma Fri Jan  9 01:29 - 01:29  (00:00)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.12.28+         Fri Jan  9 01:23 - 18:01  (16:38)    
reboot   system boot  3.12.28+         Fri Jan  9 01:23 - 18:04  (16:41)
```

The `runlevel (to lvl 0)` line appears after I did `shutdown -h now`, while the `crash` line is from `shutdown now`. Does `shutdown now` cause a "crash" which prevents it from running init scripts?

Comment: Can you run `last -x` for us? Maybe it's switching to yet a different runlevel. (I have a vague recollection it was runlevel `s`, single user mode, in slackware?)

Comment: Yes, when should I run `last -x`? After reboot, or before running `sudo shutdown now`? I'll try when I get home this afternoon. And, BTW, isn't runlevel `1` single user mode? https://wiki.debian.org/RunLevel

Comment: Anytime, as root. `last` looks at the history of your logins, reboots and runlevel changes, so it should tell you what runlevel your `shutdown` puts you in.

Comment: OK, I have added that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the file in the `rc.d` folders is important and it's not clear what you've named your symlink to your `/etc/init.d/myscript.sh`.

Examples from `/etc/rc1.d`:

```
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Nov  3  2011 K99readahead_early -> ../init.d/readahead_early
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Nov  3  2011 K99readahead_later -> ../init.d/readahead_later
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Nov  3  2011 S02lvm2-monitor -> ../init.d/lvm2-monitor
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Nov  3  2011 S13cpuspeed -> ../init.d/cpuspeed
```

If S is supplied then it'll run the script with `start`; if K is supplied it'll run the script with `stop`. The integer value is then the priority that should be run.

Comment: Yeah, should have mentioned, I used `update-rc.d` to create the symlink, so it is named something like `K02...`. I'll have a look and find out exactly what the symlink is called. But the problem is still why the script runs on `shutdown -h now`, and not on `shutdown now`.

Comment: I thought this issue was due to the different runlevel based on whether `-h` is provided or not?

Comment: Well, _if_ `shutdown now` invokes a different runlevel than `shutdown -h now` - I don't know. I believed that `shutdown` would cause runlevel `0` no matter what, but maybe I'm wrong. As said, my script runs fine when doing `shutdown -h now`, but does _not_ run on `shutdown now`. Another script in `/etc/rc1.d` also does not run on `shutdown now`, so it doesn't look like runlevel `1` is invoked. @Ulrich Schwartz suggests that it might be runlevel `S` that is getting invoked, I'll have to look into that possibility.